# Image used for parallax background is pulling from http localhost instead of the wordpress url in style.css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I created a parallax scroll effect for a wordpress site i built. Used the following html and css:

html

```
<div class="container-above"></div> 

<!-- Parallax Container element -->
<div class="parallax"></div>

<div class="container-below"></div>
```

css

```
.parallax { 
        /* The image used */
        background-image: url("https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/image.png");

        /* Set a specific height */
        height: 500px;

        /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
    }
```

I go to the page and the image doesn't appear. I go to "inspect" and get the following error:

﻿

> (index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mywebsite.com/' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://localhost/wpthemes/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/image.png'.
>   This content should also be served over HTTPS. img.png Failed to load
>   resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Which basically means that the since the image isn't under and https url, chrome won't display it because technically it's not secure. Which doesn't make much sense, because the url I am using for the image is an https pulled from the media gallery of the wordpress site I am using it for.

So I go to "view page source" and sure enough, in the style.css file, it is pulling the localhost link 'http://localhost/wpthemes/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/image.png' instead of the wordpress image link.

So I go back to the style.css sheet in FTP, but the css is still the same:

```
.parallax { 
            /* The image used */
            background-image: url("https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/image.png");

            /* Set a specific height */
            height: 500px;

            /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
```

Would anyone be able to shed some light on this? First I thought it was a cache issue, but I loaded the site in incognito mode in chrome and got the same effect and error.

I get the feeling that there is  soemthing I need to be doing with wordpress, perhaps inserting the image into the html instead of the css, but I haven't come across anything specific yet.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use a PHP function `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to help you set a relative path.

> **get_stylesheet_directory_uri():** Retrieves stylesheet directory URI for the current theme/child theme. Checks for SSL.

Put this PHP inside your `HTML`:

```
<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>
```

it will echo out your current `stylesheet directory`.

After that compare the `image path` and `stylesheet path` and do something like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/aternus.png" alt="" width="" height="" />
```

or, after finding out the `sylesheet path` you can write a `relative path` for the `image` in `CSS` like this:

```
background-image: url('./../uploads/2017/12/image.png');
// explanation: /. means current folder, ../ means one folder back (up)
```

Answer (score 0):

@logos_164

If you recently moved this site from a local dev to a live site, may I recommend that you check in your wp-admin under Settings>>General and look at what your WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are set to.

(Sometimes people will export their local dev sql wordpress database and forget to do a find/replace on the site url and end up with all the settings being localhost or *.dev)

If neither one of those addresses are localhost then that is not the problem.  Though I would do an sql export and search the file for any reference to localhost just in case there is a setting/field that still correlates to localhost.

If you did recently move this from a local dev to a live site, I would also redo my permalink settings to reset the .htaccess file.

A last resort may be to upload the image via ftp to a folder in your hosting environment and reference the location in your style.css instead of using the wordpress media upload folders.

Comment: I did as you suggested and both the Site and Wordpress URL are set to the server domain, not the localhost. I'm intrigued by your second suggestion, but not sure how to do it (sql export and search the file) would you be able to link to some documentation on how to go about this? Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: If you have access to phpMyAdmin, you can click on your wordpress database and then click on the export tab and then export your sql file into a text file.  Open this text file in any text editor or IDE (I suggest Notepad++) and search for 'localhost' and see if there are any entries in your table with 'localhost'.

Comment: Thanks, did that, yes I do have 3 entries with local host. After researching more, I think I might have done something wrong when moving the site from a local WordPress dev site to a server aide one

Comment: Easy fix.  In phpMyAdmin, drop all the tables from your live sites database.  Export your sql file from your dev setup and do a find/replace for localhost and replace with your site domain and then save and import your saved sql file into the database.  This will fix it.

Comment: I'm a little confused on this, can you link to a tutorial?

Comment: Try the wordpress plugin "better search replace", it will do everything you need without having to mess with the physical db.